# Having trouble importing firebase into my project. Importing it causes my react app to not work, it compiles but nothing shows up

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been attempting to fix this for days. I am new to firebase and wanted to add it into my react project but when I use it, my application stops working even though it compiles.

Here is my firebase config file:

```
/*
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyATcQBcBVJAYZbn9EfKNq6DjXtFdx25tss",
    authDomain: "grey-hackbu.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "grey-hackbu",
    storageBucket: "grey-hackbu.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "748662363480",
    appId: "1:748662363480:web:4faf4f4fcd12e0f20d012d",
    measurementId: "G-7GDWG2D6FF"
});

//xconst firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();


export {db, auth, storage};
*/








//Just use this for now
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyATcQBcBVJAYZbn9EfKNq6DjXtFdx25tss",
    authDomain: "grey-hackbu.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "grey-hackbu",
    storageBucket: "grey-hackbu.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "748662363480",
    appId: "1:748662363480:web:4faf4f4fcd12e0f20d012d",
    measurementId: "G-7GDWG2D6FF"
  };

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebaseApp.auth();
const storage = firebaseApp.storage();


export {db, auth, storage};
```

So the top part of the code is what I thought it should be but when I run my code it tells me that firebase is not defined so I changed it to the bottom code which allowed my code to compile. The bottom also resembles the firebase documentation so I left that.

Here is my main App.js file where I am trying to import the db so that I can use it.:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Post from './components/Post';
//import { db } from './firebase'; 

function App() {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    {
      username: "Jason Vitale",
      caption: "My first post!",
      imageURL: "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png"
    },
    {
      username: "Jason Vitale",
      caption: "My first post!",
      imageURL: "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png"
    }
  ]);
  
  //Everytime post change it goes on here
  useEffect(() =>{

  }, [])





  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <div className="app_navbar">
          <img className="app_navbar_image" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/38/38002.png" alt="" height="50" width= "50"/>
      </div>
      <h1>Jason</h1>

      {
        posts.map(post => (
          <Post username={post.username} caption={post.caption} imageURL={post.imageURL}/>
        ))
      }

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now line 4 is causing the issue. When I run npm start when that line is NOT commented out my app compiles but just shows up as a white screen which it should not be doing. However once I comment out the line, the code compiles and displays all the things that I hard coded which is correct. The compiler will not display any messages, it just says that it compiles fine.

I don't know if maybe i'm importing firebase wrong or referencing it incorrectly. Note that I do have firebase installed which I did using `npm i firebase`

I'm just unsure where to go. Any suggestions help. I wanted to be able to reference something I put in the firestore database just to test it, but `db` won't work.

Comment: If correcting the syntax for a specific Firebase version has not worked, you should post the contents of your `package.json` and any console output from your web developer console when the app shows up empty. You could try creating a new React project and following [these steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) to add the SDK to a project in case something went wrong along the way. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#latest_sdk_versions) are the latest versions of all available SDKs, the latest for the JS SDK being v9.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing here is the older (object based) syntax of Firebase SDKs v8 and earlier, and the newer (modular/functional) syntax of v9 and above. The main documentation contains examples for both, and I recommend checking out the upgrade guide for more information on how to map to the new syntax: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Comment: I think this is useful information since I am using firebase 10. Do you recommend just using an older version of firebase, or trying to fix the syntax?

Comment: I have no recommendation on which version to use, but the upgrade documentation I linked shows how to modify v8 syntax to the newer modular syntax.

Comment: alright thank you, I can't seem to resolve the issue with either fix. So ill just continue to troubleshoot.